# Aprendiendo promises, no ejecuta secuencialmente

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas, asincronismo

Estoy aprendiendo **promises**, y estuve haciendo algunos ejemplos.

Este es mi código en el que pretendo mostrar.

> lo siguiente: //uno,dos,tres,cuatro pero en lugar de eso muestra
>   asíncronamente //uno, cuatro, dos, tres

```
let promise =new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    console.log("uno");
    resolve();
});
promise.then(function(){
    console.log("dos");
    console.log("tres");
});
console.log("cuatro");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las promesas se agendan para un momento próximo. El momento exacto en el cuál se van a ejecutar las funciones no depende de vos. Sólo podés indicar el orden de ejecución, no el momento exacto.

Si querés mostrar "asíncronamente" uno, dos, tres cuatro:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('uno');
    resolve();
}).then(_ => {
  console.log('dos');
  console.log('tres');
}).then(_ => {
  console.log('cuatro');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Por otro lado, `then` devuelve una promesa. Además tenés el `catch()` "de arriba". Queda mucho mas simple. Podés, entonces, encadenar un `then` detrás de otro, lo que devuelven es una promesa. Si en algún momento hay un `throw`, entonces se ejecuta el método `catch`.

Comment: es decir que puedo unir varios .then?

Comment: Así es! Y lo que devuelvas dentro del then es una promesa :)

Answer (score 2):

¿Con qué objetivo? ¿Es solo para aprender? Yo diría que sería mejor no usar promises, ya que se trata justo de eso, que aparezcan sin orden aparente, es decir, asíncrona.

Yo intentaría esto:

```
var array=["uno","dos","tres","cuatro"]
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

... o de manera más simple, `console.log(" uno \n dos \n tres \n cuatro")`

Otra manera sería hacer un `setTimeOut` que llame a otro `setTimeout` hasta acabar el ciclo.

Comment: se trata de un ejemplo, para saber el orden de ejecucion.